# 404 error with .xml files >= 1kb

Tags: xml, http-status-code-404

I have a strange problem: basically if I try to load from a browser an .xml file, from my website, that is greater or equal to 1kb of size I see a 404 not found error.

I know that the problem is the size because I made some experiments. Basically if the file is 1.023 bytes it'll be showed correctly, but if I add a character (so it will reach 1.024 bytes of size) to one of the fields I see a 404 error, but then again if I erase a white space the .xml file is outputted correctly.

This problem sounds very strange to me, what could be the problem?

Comment: where is the code that handles this

Comment: What do you mean? It happens simply trying to load an url from the browser. I can paste some example .xml files but I don't think it would be useful.

Comment: Could you elleborate with more details like;
- Which (if any) WebServer are you using?
- Are you outputting the XML yourself or is it done by an embedded handler?

Comment: Static files are found by Apache that returns the location to nginx that finally outputs the file to the browser. The file is outputted just by requesting it from the browser (example: http://www.website.com/path/to/file.xml). I haven't encountered any problem using other kind of files. Also I forgot to say that if I change the extension of a .xml to, for example, to .png I don't see an 404 error, so the file has been found but the browser says that it's not a valid image, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's pretty much likely a problem with your server's configuration. I also had a problem like this on a server running NGinx under Plesk.

In particular I suggest you to check you cache-related directives.

Comment: Thanks for you're help, the problem was there.